# Infinite loop for itemupdated event, sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver, itemupdated

What can i do to avoid infinite loop in my itemupdated event receiver,
everytime  i call the item.Update(); the event fires again, what is the equivalent of EventFiringEnabled to sharepoint online

Comment: Have you tried to update the AfterProperties instead of updating the item directly?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to handle the race condition inside of you event reciever, as unfortunately there is no equivalent to EventFiringEnabled.

This [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/senthilkumarmani/2015/08/16/sharepoint-onlineremote-event-receiver-reritemupdateditemadded-thread-race/) show an example